# Workspace Unhealthy After Changing Computer Name

Tags: amazon-workspaces

We decided to move dev machines (PC's) into the cloud in the form of Amazon Workspaces. In simple terms, a provisioned workspace is very similar to a PC accessed via RDP. However, the scaffolding for the service assigns a 'unqiue' computer name to each workspace. We wanted to set a specific computer name and therefore we connected to the workspace and used the standard Windows technique of going into Properties on "This PC". Windows prompted to restart, which we did. Thereafter the workspace was unreachable from the Windows WorkSpaces client stating the status was Unhealthy. The WorkSpaces Management status was initially REBOOTING then PENDING. Finally it showed UNHEALTHY.

It is not unusual to want to change the computer name, particularly if modelling a current physical config into the cloud.  However it looks like this derails / confuses the workspaces scaffolding.

Question: How to make the workspace reachable again, especially if much time investment has been made configuring it?

I shall provide the answer that solved the issue for me, which I leave for others hitting this issue and in the hope that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found the basis of this answer in the Amazon Workspaces forum from the same question asked by JoeA in 2016.  It took me a while to find - see [the original post here.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=732801) which I shall paraphrase following in case this precious link breaks in the future.

Amazon's answer was:

> Changing the computer name on your WorkSpace will cause the PCoIP application to fail, so you won't be able to connect to it using the Amazon client.
>
> To connect to the workspace, you can edit the security group associated with the workspace's ENI and allow TCP traffic on port 3389 so you can RDP into it.
>
> Once you are connected to the WorkSpace, rename it back to the original name and reboot it and you should be able to connect again.

JoeA responded:

> Thank you very much for your reply, there is hope! I'm a newbie with AWS and Workspaces. Can you provide more details, or point me to a document, on how to access the Workspace using RDP? I searched the forum, but no luck.
>
> Specifically, I don't know how to "edit the security group associated with the workspace's ENI and allow TCP traffic on port 3389 so you can RDP into it" as you state. I did find under the "Directories" setting that my "Security Group" is set to "None selected". (FYI, I have only this one Workspace.) "Access to Internet" is set to "Enable", if that is a factor. Thanks.

JoeA then followed up with the solution which was, in his words:

> The changes to open the port are under the EC2 console, not the Workspaces console where I was originally looking. I found the Security Group for Workspaces, and changed Inbound traffic to allow RDP (port 3389). Then also on the EC2 console, I found Network Interfaces that shows the public IP. (I first tried to RDP using the IP shown in Workspaces console properties ("WorkSpace IP"), but that must be a local IP inside that network.) RDP'ing to the public IP, I connected and put back the original machine name, restarted, and now I can connect again using the Workspaces client again.

Thanks JoeA for that good work.